# Challenge to Highlight all string occurrences outside HTML tags

Tags: html, string, lazarus, freepascal

I'm working on a Free Pascal-Lazarus (1.4.4) project where I need to highlight (using HTML tags) all occurrences of a string with another string. However, I only want to replace the string if it is text, i.e. I must ignore occurrences inside HTML tags.

For example:
I want to highlight all ocurrences of word grid (must be case insensitive):

```
<p class="Body"><span style="layout-grid-mode: line;" lang="EN-GB">Rome was the most important city in the world. Grid just for test. Grid again...</span></p>
```

Like This:

```
<p class="Body"><span style="layout-grid-mode: line;" lang="EN-GB">Rome was the most important city in the world. <span style="background-color: #FA8072 ; color: #ffffff;">Grid</span> just for test. <span style="background-color: #FA8072 ; color: #ffffff;">Grid</span> again...</span></p>
```

Please, observe that I have to ignore the word grid inside the HTML tag and change only the text.

Best regards

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=parsing+html

Comment: Please @Waxi, can you explain better?

Comment: what @Waxi ment you need to somehow parse the html document. For fp something in line with [fasthtmlparser](http://z505.com/cgi-bin/powtils/docs/1.6/idx.cgi?file=fasthtmlparser), it is a part of fp now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rustic solution using regular expressions. I assumed 1° that in text the word "grid" is neither preceded nor followed by a hyphen; 2° that in tags the word "grid" is always preceded or followed by an hyphen. If these assumptions are true, maybe this code could be a way to solve your problem.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$IFDEF FPC}{$MODE DELPHI}{$ENDIF}

uses
  regexpr;

const
  SUBJECT = '<p class="Body"><span style="layout-grid-mode: line;" lang="EN-GB">Rome was the most important city in the world. Grid just for test. Grid again...</span></p>';
  PATTERN = '([^-])([Gg][Rr][Ii][Dd])([^-])';
  REPLACEMENT = '$1<span style="background-color: #FA8072 ; color: #ffffff;">$2</span>$3';

var
  result: string;

begin  
  result := ReplaceRegExpr(
    PATTERN,
    SUBJECT,
    REPLACEMENT,
    TRUE // Use substitution
  );

  WriteLn(result);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

fpc has a nice html parser in the unit "fasthtmlparser". It provides an event `OnFoundText` which fires whenever the parser finds html text (outside tags). This text is provided as a parameter, you can search the "Grid" in it and replace by whatever you want. Then you append this modified text to the previously found/modified texts.

Here is a working console project. For simplicity I am only calling `StringReplace()` to find the "Grid", but of course this will also replace "Grid" if contained inside a word - but you can apply Roland Chastain's RegExpr solution to avoid this.

```
program Project1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  fasthtmlparser, SysUtils;

type
  TMyHTMLParser = class(THTMLParser)
  private
    FModifiedText: String;
    procedure FoundTextHandler(Text: string);
  public
    property ModifiedText: String read FModifiedText write FModifiedText;
  end;

procedure TMyHTMLParser.FoundTextHandler(Text: String);
begin
  Text := StringReplace(Text,
    'Grid',
    '<span style="background-color: #FA8072 ; color: #ffffff;">Grid</span>',
    [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]
  );
  FModifiedText := FModifiedText + Text;
end;

const
  html =
    '<p class="Body">' +
    '<span style="layout-grid-mode: line;" lang="EN-GB">' +
    'Rome was the most important city in the world. '+
    'Grid just for test. Grid again...'+
    '</span>'+
    '</p>:';
var
  parser: TMyHTMLParser;

begin
  parser := TMyHTMLParser.Create(html);
  try
    parser.ModifiedText := '';
    parser.OnFoundText := @parser.FoundTextHandler;
    parser.Exec;
    WriteLn(parser.ModifiedText);
  finally
    parser.Free;
  end;
end.
```